# How Do I Run Xcode

Tags: install, xcode

I just downloaded and installed Xcode on my MacBook Pro, but I don't see it under Applications or Utilities.  I also don't see a shortcut at the bottom.  How do I run it?

Comment: Also note you can use Spotlight to open applications. Press CMD+Space and type the name "Xcode" and it should be the first hit under the Applications heading.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Xcode is located in /Developer/Applications/Xcode.app. Double-click it to open it. If you want, you can make an alias to it in your applications folder.

Answer (score 1):

After you buy Xcode from the App Store you will be left with an 'Install Xcode' application in your `Applications` folder -- run that. It'll do the actual install and after all of that is said and done you'll have a `/Developer/Applications/Xcode.app` application in your PATH.

Comment: And after the installation, be sure to archive the "Install Xcode" app and get it off your hard drive. It takes up 3GB of hard drive space and does nothing.

Comment: note this is for Xcode 4.0-4.2 - 4.3 runs from /Applications